# Module ... is not backed by gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, intellij-13

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Pro 13.1.2.  Never used any versions below 13.

When trying to run `build.gradle` from IDE I get the message:

> Module  is not backed by gradle

I can run this script from the command line just fine.

The "root" directory has both `.gradle` and `gradle` sub-directories and, in general its structure is very similar to another module from the same project where I can run its build from IDE without problems.

Any suggestions on further troubleshooting?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't set up the IDE project via "Import Project" and then pointing to a Gradle project. You can also try to link the IDE project to a Gradle project in the "Gradle" window. Not sure what you mean by "run build.gradle from IDE".

Comment: Yes, it was not set-up in "Gradle" window.  I built this module as new IDEA module, never imported it.  Now it works. Thank you.  If you care to post the same as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: In IntelliJ 2016 you can accomplish this by closing the project and reimporting it, pointing intellij specifically at the build.gradle file.

Comment: This can happen when you did not import the project as a Gradle project. To solve this:
Close the project. Delete its .idea folder. Reopen the project using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you didn't set up the IDE project via "Import Project" and then pointing to a Gradle project, you may have to link the IDE project to the Gradle project. This can be done in the "Gradle" window.

Comment: Much obliged. Thanks again.

Comment: Stupid question - for a non-gradle project, how do I find the "Gradle" window? It doesnt seem to be available via ctrl+shift+a -> "Gradle" (enter). Nor can I see any relevant facets (other than Groovy, which doesnt help either)

Comment: `Tools > Grails > Change SDK Version` did the trick for me.


Edit: IntelliJ 14.1 - OS X 10.9.5

Comment: There is no `Grails` in the Tools menu.  IntelliJ 14.1.4.  OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Also a restart of intellij might be a good idea since at startup `build.gradle` is identified and the project is set up.

Comment: @MicahZoltu still true for Idea 15.0.1

Comment: The simpliest way is just to click `File/Open...` and to select the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 49):

The answer that worked for me is to **restart IntelliJ - at startup build.gradle is identified and the project is set up.**

The only thing that worked for me was to use the menu `File > Close Project` and reopen it. IDEA popped up a dialog saying "Import project from Gradle files" or something to that effect.

---

**Dead ends**: Below is a list of dead ends, so don't waste your time with them. I kept seeing "module is not backed by gradle" despite following all these proposed solutions:

1. There was no Gradle tool window, so I couldn't synchronize the project
2. Clicking `File > Open` gradle.build opens the file for editing and doesn't solve the issue
3. Creating a run configuration that runs gradle has no effect, even after I saw a `build/` folder created
4. Runing `./gradlew` from the commandline only creates files for gradle and doesn't fix IntelliJ

Comment: Only your advice actually helps me.

Comment: Ever since I created this answer, it has consistently been upvoted.

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this problem by clicking in the Menu

```
--> "Run" 
--> "Edit Configurations" 
--> [+] The little plus in the top left corner 
--> "Gradle"
```

With the new created run configuration it worked.
I hope this will help some of you.

Answer (score 9):

Tools > Grails > Change SDK Version

Comment: Worked great for me on ubuntu with intellij 14

Comment: Worked for me (OS X 10.10.5, Grails 2.4.4 app with grails and groovy installed using sdkman).  Saw the problem as a result of the recent conversion of gvm to sdkman, so part of the issue was correcting the global library path for grails in the IDEA settings.

Answer (score 5):

Like others have said, none of the other answers worked for me. The only thing that worked was:

Close the project, then import it as a Gradle project.

Answer (score 4):

For a non-gradle project, you can also remove the module from the project and re-import it. This will help avoid the message "module is not backed by gradle".

Answer (score 3):

I'm using android studio, intellij. 
Try this:

- Tools > Android > (sync project with gradle files)
- Run gradle build

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not select the project directory when importing
2. Select the gradle file to import as a Gradle project
3. I always use Local Gradle Distribution and Offline work to build, then switch back.
4. It will auto build and you will see the gradle task in task window.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened for me because I chose a different name for my project than my artifactID. In order to prevent this problem to happen, make sure your project name is the same as your artifactID.

Answer (score 0):

You may have originally created the project via `File->New->Project From Version Control`. This doesn't seem to always set the project up as a Gradle project, even if there is a build.gradle in the root directory.
To solve this:-

1. Close IntelliJ.
2. Delete the .idea folder in the project.
3. Start IntelliJ and select 'Open'.
4. Navigate to the project folder and open it.

The project will be recognised as Gradle and be set up as such.