# Error occurs when cocos 2d-x-3.15.1 project compiling in android studio

Tags: compiler-errors, cocos2d-x-3.0

Don't know how to solve this problem of cocos 2d-x-3.15.1

```
 Warning:android-validator: Suspicious module dependency proj.android -> android: Android application module depends on other application module. Possibly, you should change type of module 'android' to 'Library' or change the dependency scope to 'Provided'.
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:139)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:336)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.loadDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:80)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:136)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] Failed to load dx.jar
    Error:Android Pre Dex: [EngineDataManager.jar] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.dx.command.DxConsole
```

Installing android studio 2.3.3 than still its showing this some error same like android studio 2.1.1. I don't understand what was the problem in it.. Please help me out from that!!

```
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] Failed to load dx.jar
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:139)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:336)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:136)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.loadDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:80)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.dx.command.DxConsole



Error Occur at the time of Compiling the project in android studio. Its showing some dx.jar file error and some error which are unable to understand it. So please help me out from this error!





Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        Information:05/07/2017 12:24 PM - Compilation completed with 13 errors and 0 warnings in 5s 253ms
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] Failed to load dx.jar
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.dx.command.DxConsole
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.loadDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:80)
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:136)
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:336)
        Error:Android Pre Dex: [annotations.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:139)
        Information:java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
        Information:java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
        G:\Kunal\Gaming\cocos2d\cocos\platform\android\java\src\org\cocos2dx\lib\Cocos2dxSound.java
```

Comment: your targetSDK ?

Comment: In the project structure - SDK - Build Target :- Android API 25

Comment: what is inside `gradle.properties` file ?

Comment: TARGET_SDK_VERSION should be 13

Comment: I have done it to be 13 and in my project there is not gradle file.

Comment: Do you've android studio project module ?

Comment: use 13 as target ?

Comment: Yes i created the new project in android studio

Comment: Android NDK break compatibility since API 21 so in my suggestion you should target android-13.

Comment: I target android 13 but still its showing the same error

Comment: I already tested on cocos 2d-x-3.15.1, working fine for me.

Comment: your AndroidStudio version ?

Comment: My android studio version is 2.1.2

Comment: use `Android Studio 2.3` or greater

Comment: Okay @AbhishekAryan

Comment: I upgrade my android studio its 2.3.3 but still its showing error. Are u please show me the snapshot of target sdk.

Comment: try to downgrade build tools to 25.0.3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have had same issue. 
Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789838/android-studio-failed-to-load-dx-jar) solution and worked!

The solution is for Ubuntu and OSX but I am sure it will work for Windows as well.

Comment: In android studio i installed all build tools but still its not work it